# AngularJS in Cover of Ghost Blog not Working

Tags: angularjs, ghost-blog

This is my basic code:

```
<div class="ebook-wrapper" ng-app="" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
  <p>{{1+2}}</p>
</div>
```

It works within the posts:
http://autofokus-marketing.de/angularjs/

If I apply it in my main page cover right between

```
<div class="ebook-form">
  <p>{{1+2}}</p>
  <h2>Das Geheimnis....
```

http://autofokus-marketing.de/

It throws me a parse error:

> 500
>   [index.hbs] Parse error on line 23: ...
>
> {{1+2}}
>
> -----------------------^ Expecting 'ID', 'DATA', got 'INVALID

Comment: Seems to be working on the example link.

Comment: As mentioned it works within the post. But the same code doesn't if I put it on my main page into index.hbs. / I didn't otherwise there would be no page.

Comment: Says Ghost templates aren't compatible with angular.  https://ghost.org/forum/using-ghost/2181-using-angularjs-instead-of-handlebars/

Comment: Ok thanks. Maybe that's the same issue when I try to integrate my Mailchimp forms into the template. Looking for a way to make a signup form into the cover any ideas?